# Delete and recreate identity column and fetch the newly created values in an update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a four tables called plandescription, plandetail and analysisdetail.
The table plandescription has the columns DetailQuestionID which is the primary and identity column and a QuestionDescription column.

The table plandetail consists of the column PlanDetailID which the primary and identity column, DetailQuestionID which is the foreign key attribute of plandescription table and a planID column

The third table analysisdetail consists of a analysisID which the primary and identity column, PlanDetailID which is the foreign key attribute of plandetail table and a scenario.

Below is the schema of the three tables

I have a two web form that will insert, update and delete data into these three tables in a two transaction. One web form will perform CRUD operations in plandescription and  plandetail table. When the user inserts QuestionDescription and planid in this web form, I will insert the QuestionDescription Value in the plandescription table and will generate a DetailQuestionID value and this value is fed to the plandetail table with the planid. Here I will generate a PlanDetailID.

Once this transaction is done, I will show the second web form in which the user enters the scenario and this will be mapped with the plandescription using the PlanDetailID.

This schema cannot be changes as this is the client requirement.
When I insert values I don’t have any problem. However when I update existing data, I need to delete existing PlanDetailID in the plandetail table and recreate PlanDetailID data for that DetailQuestionID and planID. This is because, the user will be adding or deleting a planID associated with the QuestionDescription.

Once I recreate PlanDetailID for that DetailQuestionID and planID, I need to update the old PlanDetailID  with the new PlanDetailID in the third table analysisdetail for the associated analysisID.

I created a #Temp table called #DetailTable to insert the values analysisID, planid and old PlanDetailID and new  PlanDetailID  so that I can have them in update statement once I delete the data from plandetail table for that PlanDetailID.

Then I deleted the plandetailid from the plandetail table and recreate PlanDetailID for that DetailQuestionID. During my recreation I fetched the new PlanDetailID’s created into another temp table called #InsertedRows

After this I am running a while loop to update the temp table #DetailTable  with the newly created PlanDetailID for the appropriate planID’s.
The problem is here. When I have the same number of planID’s for example 2 planID’s 1,2 I will have only two old PlanDetailID and new PlanDetailID for that planID and analysisID.

But When I add a new PlanID or remove a existing planID I am getting null value for that newly added or deleted planID.
This is affecting my update statement of  analysisdetail table as PlanDetailID cannot be null.

I tried to remove the Null value from the #DetailTable by running the update statement of  analysisdetail in a while loop however its not working.

Can any one help me to solve this? Below is the code that I created.

```
DECLARE @cID INT = 8
DECLARE @DQID INT = 1380

/*------- I need the query to run for the below three data. 
Here i'm updating my Pids that already exists in my database*/

DECLARE @Pids VARCHAR(MAX) = '2,4,5'

---DECLARE @Pids VARCHAR(MAX) = '2,4'
---DECLARE @Pids VARCHAR(MAX) = '1,2,4'

CREATE TABLE #DetailTable (
    Id INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
    ,analID INT
    ,PlanID INT
    ,OldPlanID INT
    ,NewPlanID INT
    )

INSERT INTO #DetailTable (
    analID
    ,PlanID
    ,OldPlanID
    ) (
    SELECT analID
    ,cfpd.PlanID
    ,cfpd.PlanDID FROM [dbo].[AnalDetail] rd INNER JOIN [dbo].[PlanDetail] cfpd ON rd.PlanDID = cfpd.PlanDID WHERE cfpd.DQID = @DQID
    )

---- Delete previous functionalplan id
DELETE
FROM dbo.PlanDetail
WHERE DQID = @DQID;

---- Insert New plandetail id for the category
CREATE TABLE #InsertedRows (
    Id INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
    ,NewPlanDID INT
    ,PlanID INT
    )

INSERT INTO dbo.plandetail (
    DQID
    ,planid
    )
OUTPUT inserted.PlanDID
    ,inserted.planid
INTO #InsertedRows
SELECT @DQID
    ,data
FROM dbo.fndatasplit(@functionalPids, ',');

--- Get Latest PlanDID
DECLARE @loop INT

SET @loop = 1

DECLARE @NewPlanDID AS INT
DECLARE @FPlanId AS INT

WHILE (
        @loop <= (
            SELECT Count(*)
            FROM #InsertedRows
            )
        )
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (
            SELECT FunctionPlan
            FROM #DetailTable
            )
    BEGIN
        SELECT @FPlanId = PlanID
        FROM #InsertedRows
        WHERE ID = @loop

        SELECT @NewPlanDID = newPlanDID
        FROM #InsertedRows
        WHERE ID = @loop

        UPDATE #DetailTable
        SET NewPlanID = @NewPlanDID
        WHERE PlanID = @FPlanId

        SET @loop = @loop + 1
    END
END

--- Update AnalDetail Table with New PlanDetail
DECLARE @intFlag INT

SET @intFlag = 1

DECLARE @analID INT
DECLARE @NewPlanID INT

WHILE (
        @intFlag <= (
            SELECT Count(*)
            FROM #DetailTable
            WHERE NewPlanID IS NOT NULL
            )
        )
BEGIN
    SELECT @analID = analID
    FROM #DetailTable
    WHERE ID = @intFlag

    SELECT @NewPlanID = NewPlanID
    FROM #DetailTable
    WHERE ID = @intFlag

    UPDATE dbo.AnalDetail
    SET PlanDID = @NewPlanID
    WHERE analID = @analID

    SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1
END

SELECT *
FROM #DetailTable

SELECT *
FROM #InsertedRows

SELECT *
FROM AnalDetail
```

--- Function DataSplit

```
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[fnDataSplit]    Script Date: 25-07-2015 12:21:17 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnDataSplit]  
(  
 @RowData nvarchar(2000),  
 @SplitOn nvarchar(5)  
)    
RETURNS @RtnValue table   
(  
 Id int identity(1,1),  
 Data nvarchar(100)  
)   
AS    
BEGIN   
 Declare @Cnt int  
 Set @Cnt = 1  

 While (Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)>0)  
 Begin  
  Insert Into @RtnValue (data)  
  Select   
   Data = ltrim(rtrim(Substring(@RowData,1,Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)-1)))  

  Set @RowData = Substring(@RowData,Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)+1,len(@RowData))  
  Set @Cnt = @Cnt + 1  
 End  

 Insert Into @RtnValue (data)  
 Select Data = ltrim(rtrim(@RowData))  

 Return  
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself after exploring things in google.

I created a temp table and fetched the identity values of the inserted rows using the OUTPUT command to the temp table.

from the temp table is got the new identity values.

below is the code

```
    INSERT INTO dbo.plandetail (
    DQID
    ,planid
    )
OUTPUT inserted.PlanDID
    ,inserted.planid
INTO #InsertedRows
SELECT @DQID
    ,data
FROM dbo.fndatasplit(@functionalPids, ',');
```